# How to add values to chart using delegate in c#

Tags: c#

I am having a chart with two series primary and secondary y-axis.I want to add values to chart using delegates.When I am adding,getting "cross thread operation not valid" exception. Please refer my code below.

```
    public delegate void SetTextDel(string Xvalue,double Y1value,double 

    Y2Value);
    Thread Thread1=new Thread(createGraph);

    private void SetText(string XValue,double Y1Value,double Y2Value)
    {
         if (this.chart1.InvokeRequired)
         {
             this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y1Value);        
             this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y2Value);       
         }       
    }

    private void createGraph()  
    { 
        while(true)
        { 
             string time;
             int  Y1value =0;
             int  Y2value =0;

             time="abc";
             Y1value = 10;
             Y2value = 20;

             SetTextDel = new SetTextDel(SetText);
             SetText(time,oilvalue,tempvalue);

             Y1value +=5;
             Y2value +=5;
        }       
   }

   private void startbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Thread1.Start();
   }
```

Comment: If `InvokeRequired` is `true` then you actually suppose to invoke, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/142069/1997232) answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace

```
         this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y1Value);        
         this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y2Value);
```

with this if your class derives from Form:

```
         BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
             this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y1Value);        
             this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y2Value);  
         }));
```

or with this if your class derives from Page:

```
         Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => {
             this.chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y1Value);        
             this.chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(XValue, Y2Value);  
         }));
```

Comment: I tried above code but it is showing error "The name Dispatcher does not exist in the current context".

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri Could you show your class declaration (for the class that SetText() belongs too)?

Comment: My class declaration is "public partial class Frm_Main : Form"

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri Makes sense. I updated the answer.

Comment: I tried above code and is working perfectly.Thanks a lot.